# Clarification on the Royal Garden from Puerto Rico expansion 2

Tags: puerto-rico, puerto-rico-expansion-2

The Royal Garden states:

> At game end, the owner of the occupied royal garden takes 1 VP for each noble on his **island**.  As each noble is normally worth 1 VP (whether on a building, plantation or in San Juan), with the occupied royal garden each is worth 2 VPs to that player".

Puerto Rico defines "island" as the twelve spaces at the bottom of the board to place plantation tiles; the Royal Garden states that you get 1 VP for each noble on his **island** (which I would assume means "nobles on plantations") but then goes on to state that nobles in San Juan and buildings are worth 1 extra VP as well.

So... which is it?  Do nobles on island tiles get the extra VP, or nobles on your entire board get the extra VP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, a player's **island** is their game board, unless explicitly referring to plantations.  Its semantically tricky, as the island on the board contains San Juan which is implicitly the player's city.

I admit, that's kind of shaky reasoning.

With regards to the Royal Garden explicitly, an unofficial translation of the original rules was:

> At game’s end the owner of the Garden
>   gains 2 VP for each Noble he owns
>   instead of the usual 1VP/Noble. This
>   is true wherever his Nobles are:
>   building, plantation, San Juan, etc...

[(source)](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/43381/english-rules-v1-0)

And it makes more sense in terms of design as the rest of the expansion clearly wants you to place Nobles on buildings.

Comment: Interesting note about the translation!  I agree, it's shaky, and I'm torn between "rules as written" versus "intent", but I'm inclined to agree that it's a mistranslation.  Sure makes Villa + Jeweler + Royal Gardens nasty if you can pull it off.

Answer (score -2):

You win 2VP per noble in the island and 1VP per noble in the city or san juan IMO. This is more balanced.