# Royal Supplier in Puerto Rico Expansion II -- is it all or nothing?

Tags: puerto-rico, puerto-rico-expansion-2

The rules for the Royal Supplier state:

> The owner of an occupied Royal Supplier can supply the Royal Warehouse (the supply) with a number of goods from his windrose equal to the number of nobles on his island and take 1 VP for each.
>   NOTE:  Such supplied goods must all be of different kinds (no duplicates).  Regardless of other buildings or abilities, the player may gain no additional bonuses from supplying these goods to the royal warehouse.

Now, we've got two things going on here - "goods equal to the number of nobles on his island" and "must all be of different kinds".  Assuming that "island" means game board (as answered [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/229/clarification-on-the-royal-garden-from-puerto-rico-expansion-2)), how do you resolve this if you have more nobles than distinct goods?  And do you have to send all or nothing?

For example:

Scenario 1: I have 6 nobles on my island.  There are 2 corn, 1 indigo, 2 sugar, 3 tobacco and 1 coffee on my windrose.  I clearly can't supply 6 barrels of goods, because there are only 5 distinct types in the game.  Do I send 5 distinct barrels to the royal supply in this case?

Scenario 2: I have 2 nobles on my island,  There are 2 corn, 1 indigo and 1 sugar on my windrose.  If I choose to use the Royal Supplier, can I only ship 1 good to the royal supply, or do I have to supply 2 distinct barrels, since I have 2 nobles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can find no ruling on this, but there's *some* precedent to work with.

In the first expansion, the Small Wharf:

> A player may ship different barrels of
>   goods during one of his turns during
>   the captain phase, but he gets only 1
>   VP for every two barrels he ships.

Further clarifications on that building show that a player can ship < 2 goods*, and need not ship all remaining goods.

So, I'd reason based on precedent (and in the absence of any other errata) that buildings that modify the captain phase allow the player to choose the selection of goods involved.

Thus,

Scenario 1: You can send **up to** 5 goods (1 of each kind) to the royal treasury.

Scenario 2: Likewise, you may send **up to** 2 goods, provided they are different, to the royal treasury.

<sub>*There's some deviousness to be had in combination with Lighthouse, and effectively trading for 1 doubloon at the end of every Captain.</sub>